# Date Range - Issues retrieving values in date range when date is saved as a varchar formatted: DD-MON-YY

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date, to-char

In a table I have no control over, I have to fetch values within a date range.  The date is saved as a varchar in an odd format of dd-mon-yy e.g. 01-Jan-24.

I have tried combinations of TRUNC, TO_DATE, TO_CHAR, but have not had luck.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  For example, currently,

```
BETWEEN TO_DATE(‘02-Oct-23’, 'dd-mon-rr') AND TO_DATE(‘14-Jan-24’, 'dd-mon-rr’)
```

is sending results from January of 2023.  I'm sure this is a relatively simple gap in my knowledge, but I haven't been able to find a simple solution, so here we are.  Will respond, if I find the solution.

Comment: "TO_DATE(02-Oct-23, 'dd-mon-rr') and TO_DATE(01-14-24, 'dd-mon-rr)" is malformed in several ways, and "format of dd-mon-rr e.g. Jan-01-24" also doesn't match. Please at least give accurate information so we know what's actually happening. And are you sure the date values are actually stored as strings, or is that just how your client is displaying them? A [mre] would be helpful, including column definition, sample data, and your actual code and results.

Comment: Very sorry.  Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find values from the table within a date range then convert your column values from `VARCHAR2` to a `DATE` using `TO_DATE` on the left-hand side of the `BETWEEN` filter:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_DATE(date_string, 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')
       BETWEEN DATE '2023-10-02' AND DATE '2024-01-14'
```

*(Note: you can use date literals on the right-hand side of the filter.)*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (date_string VARCHAR2(9));

INSERT INTO table_name (date_string)
SELECT '14-Jan-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01-Oct-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '02-Oct-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '31-Dec-23' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '01-Jan-24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '14-Jan-24' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '15-Jan-24' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DATE_STRING |
| --- |
| 02-Oct-23 |
| 31-Dec-23 |
| 01-Jan-24 |
| 14-Jan-24 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lNG3KohG)

Comment: I guess in 26 years (in 2050) there will be another "Year-2000 Bug" due to this. Luckily we will be retired at this time :-)